# Remove rows which cells do not match the column class

Tags: r, data-cleaning

So, similarly to removing NA values, I need to remove rows which cell values do not match the column class. For example

So for this example, I want to be able to remove rows of Andy, Aaron and Dorothy. For Andy's Gender it is 12 but it should only be "Male" or "Female". AS for Aaron, Status is NA so i would like to remove that too.
And lastly for Dorothy, her age is "abc" instead of a numeric.

```
Name    Age Gender  Status
Tom 12  Male    Married
Dom 41  Male    Single
Kelvin  23  Male    Married
Tim 12  Male    Single
Andy    42  12  Single
Aaron   12  Male    NA
Dorothy abc Female  Married
Nathan  34  Male    Single
```

sorry for the formatting im new to stackoverflow

Comment: Classes are defined by columns and not rows so a row cannot not match the column class. When a column contains a single value with a character value then the whole column becomes a character column.When you have, say, a value 12 for `Gender` then that is considered the character string `"12"`. You will need to specify your own rules as to which values are acceptable for each column.

Comment: Yes! That is what I want in the end. But what if i am presented with this dataset and asked to cleanse it instead? Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: For Age, `dat$Age <- as.numeric(dat$Age)` will mark invalid numbers (e.g. "abc") as NA. For Gender, `dat$Gender <- factor(dat$Gender, levels=c("Male", "Female"))` will mark invalid category (e.g. "12") as NA.  `na.exclude(dat)` will remove all rows containing at least one NA value.

Comment: Hi Adam, Thanks for the help!! For the Gender it worked perfectly. As for Age, when i used as.numeric(dat$Age) they changed the values of the entire column completely. Turned out the code was instead as.numeric(as.character(dat$Age))
Thank you and resolved.

Answer (score 0):

For each column, there should be a class assigned to them. However, for this case there wasn't. Solution provided by Adam Quek was helpful!

For columns that are class() **numeric**, e.g. dat$Age <- as.numeric(as.character(dat$Age))

For columns that are class() **factor**, e.g. dat$Gender <- factor(dat$Gender, levels=c("Male", "Female"))

These codes above changes abnormalities to NA values and lastly na.exclude(dat) should do the work.